# ContextErrorException on a nested form containing a file field

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to do this simple task :

I have a "Company" class which contains :

```php
/**
 * @var Document
 */
private $logo;


/**
 * Set logo
 *
 * @param Document $logo
 * @return Company
 */
public function setLogo(Document $logo = null)
{
    $this->logo = $logo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get logo
 *
 * @return Document
 */
public function getLogo()
{
    return $this->logo;
}
```

the logo property is a document entity.

Here is my CompanyType() :

```php
    $builder->add('name', 'text', array(
        'required' => false
    ));
    $builder->add('logo', new DocumentType(), array(
        'required' => false
    ));
```

I'm simply trying to save a new Company but I get this error :

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
Proxies\__CG__\Teacup\UserBundle\Entity\Company::setLogo() must be an instance of
Teacup\FileBundle\Entity\Document, array given, called in 
/Users/jansel/Sites/spm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php
on line 360 and defined in 
/Users/jansel/Sites/spm/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__TeacupUserBundleEntityCompany.php line 293
```

I really just followed simple examples on the sf2 cookbook and openclassroom, I don't understand why I'm failing so much. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error is in your custom form type **DocumentType**. The option '**data_class**' must be defined and have the following value: **My/Namespace/Model/Document**. Modify with wathever your namespace for **Document** actually is.

If your problem persists, you should provide us with the code of your **DocumentType** custom field.